# Call Javascript function within Bootstrap button

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a javascript code which I would like to put it in a function called SleepTime so I can pass in value and then call this function when I click on a button in an html page.  Here's my code.

```
<script>
    function SleepTime(value) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ajaxSubmit").click(function (){
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#progressBarCenter').modal('toggle');
                }, value);
            });
        });
    }
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#progressBarCenter" id="ajaxSubmit" onclick="SleepTime(2000);" > Execute Script</button>
```

I get an error when I ran the above code.  It said the function is undefined but I did define it?? How do I call this function so I can pass in the value??

tks

Comment: what is the point of adding document.ready inside sleepTime ? its irrelevant remove it first .

Comment: baically you need to remove sleepTime function , it will get bounded to the button as you are adding click handler inside document ready.

Comment: "It said the function is undefined" — Which function? You call several functions in that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this , the correct way of doing this , hope this helps:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ajaxSubmit").click(function (){
                    var sleepTime =$(this).attr('sleepTime');
                setTimeout(function() {

                                    //$('#progressBarCenter').modal('toggle');
                    console.log('will get printed after 2 seconds')
                }, sleepTime);
            });
 });


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#progressBarCenter" id="ajaxSubmit" sleepTime=2000 > Execute Script</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you miss-used here:

1. Please do not use `$(document).ready()` inside another function,
   `SleepTime()`, as `$(document).ready()` is supposed to be executed
   after DOM elements already loaded.
2. You call function `SleepTime()` one in you attribute `onclick()`, and you defined `click()` event listener inside function `SleepTime()`, this as far as I concern, it never be executed.

The correct way is as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function SleepTime(value) {
    alert(value);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#progressBarCenter').modal('toggle');
    }, value);
  }

  $('#ajaxSubmit').click(function() {
    SleepTime(2000);
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#progressBarCenter" id="ajaxSubmit"> Execute Script</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do one of these solutions

First One, using a java script function
-remove data-toggle="modal" data-target="#progressBarCenter"
-remove document ready, and click event listener from the function
-then call function on onclick

```
   <script>
            function SleepTime(value) {
               setTimeout(function() {
                  $('#progressBarCenter').modal('toggle');
               }, value);
             }
        </script>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="ajaxSubmit" onclick="SleepTime(2000);" > Execute Script</button>
```

Second One, Using a JQuery event
-remove data-toggle="modal" data-target="#progressBarCenter"
-remove the function and put the code inside jQuery event listener
-remove onclick attribute from html

```
    <script>   
var value = 2000;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#ajaxSubmit").click(function (){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $('#progressBarCenter').modal('toggle');
                        }, value);
                    });
                });  
    </script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="ajaxSubmit" > Execute Script</button>
```